# Why the $\delta$ in this proof (Rudin 3.7)?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I am confused on why it is necessary to define the sequence converging to $q$ in this manner in Rudin's theorem 3.7?:

> **Proof** $\ \ $ Let $E^*$ be the set of all subsequential limits of $\{p_n\}$ and let $q$ be a limit point of $E^*$. We have to show that $q\in E^*$.
> $\qquad$ Choose $n_1$ so that $p_{n_1}\neq q$. (If no such $n_1$ exists, then $E^*$ has only one point, and there is nothing to prove.) Put $\delta=d(q,p_{n_1})$. Suppose $n_1,...,n_{i-1}$ are chosen. Since $q$ is a limit point of $E^*$, there is an $x\in E^*$ with $d(x,q)<2^{-i}\delta$. Since $x\in E^*$, there is an $n_i>n_{i-1}$ such that $d(x,p_{n_i})<2^{-i}\delta$. Thus $$d(q,p_{n_i})\leq 2^{1-i}\delta$$ for $i=1,2,3,...$. This says that $\{p_{n_i}\}$ converges to $q$. Hence $q\in E^*$.

For instance, why not just start from the $5$th line and say:Since $q$ is a limit point of $E^*$, for each $i \in \mathbb{N}$, there is an $x \in E^*$ such that $d(x,q)<2^{-i}$. Since $x \in E^*$, there is an $n_i>n_{i-1}$ such that $d(x,p_{n_i})<2^{-i}$. So that
$$d(p_{n_i},q)<2^{1-i}$$
So that $\{p_{n_i}\}\rightarrow q$?

What is the point of setting $\delta=d(q,p_{n_1})$?Why even have it as a factor in $2^{1-i}\delta$?Is it necessary for the induction?

Comment: You are confused pretty much because you want to be confused. You _can_ in fact do as you say, by definition, there is a sequence $q_{n_i}$ in $E^*$ such that $d(q, q_{n_i}) < 2^{-i-1}.$ Since $q_{n_i}$ is the limit of a subsequence of $(p_{\varphi_i(n)})$ (here $\varphi_i$ is a strictly increasing function of $\mathbf{N}$ into itself) there is a an index $N_i > N_{i - 1}$ such that $d(p_{N_i}, q) < 2^{-i}.$ Q.E.D.

However, as you say, if I were to read Rudin's book (btw, don't, it is a bad book anyway), I'd be confused too, as with pretty much everything he wrote.

Comment: I think your proof is perfectly correct ($x\neq q$).
However, Rudin has the same reasoning, but only more verbose. However, I read Rudin with pleasure in my time.

Comment: @baharampuri I am really sorry to hear that. Rudin book is _only_ popular because he was the first american to write a modern book in mathematical analysis, but there were French and Russian books far better, far more complete, far more geometric and far more intuitive than Rudin's which has nothin to add except he is much shorter as he devoided all intuition and geometry. Worst part is that he does things in a rather repetitive manner, anyway, I am not going to make this a tirade.

Comment: @kabenyuk does the constant factor of $\delta$ in the upper bound imply $q \neq x$?

Comment: If $q = x,$ then you are done since $x \in E^*.$ So you can safely assume $x \neq q.$

Comment: @WillM. then what is the point of setting $\delta=d(q,p_{n_1})$?Why even have it as a factor in $2^{1-i}\delta$?Is it necessary for the induction?

Comment: @WillM. I always liked Rudin but I like the idea that there are more intuitive and geometric books. Do you have the titles of those books and are there English translations?

Comment: @JohnDouma Apparently, I got my dates wrong and Rudin was the first book in Mathematical Analysis widely available, it just so happened he was American. If I were to teach an analysis class, I'd probably stick with Rudin (which I really don't like) and supplement it with Vladimir Zorich's books which he adds a bit of history and it is quite geometric. My former school had several good calculus books by Mir Publishers but I don't quite remember the name of the authors, the name Petrovich kinda sounds familiar.

Comment: @JohnDouma I also like Diudonne's foundation of Modern Analysis. This my be odd since he is even more meagre than Rudin but contrary to Rudin, Dieduonné has a constructioninst approach so he doesn't prove the same theorem in two different contexts. He does metric, then Banach, then Hilbert, then spaces of functions (for example, series of real number are treated as a special case of Banach spaces and so are series of Banach-space valued functions, Rudin's approach to do series is to treat three different versions, that confused me quite a lot back then, like "what is true in what context?").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative proof of that fact without that admittedly weird $\delta.$

**Theorem.** The set of limit points of a sequence $(p_n)$ is closed.

*Proof.* Let $E'$ be the set of limit points of the sequence $(p_n)$ (i.e. the set of all subsequential limits). Suppose $q$ is a limit point of $E'.$ By definition, there is a sequence $(q_i)$ defined in $E'$ such that $d(q_i, q) \to 0.$ Thus, by choosing a subsequence should the need arise, we may assume that $d(q_i, q) < \dfrac{1}{2^{i+1}}.$ Now, $q_i \in E',$ so by definition, there is a strictly increasing $\varphi_i:\mathbf{N} \to \mathbf{N}$ such that $p_{\varphi_i(n)} \to q_i.$ Define now $N_1$ to be the first natural number such that all $n \geq N_1$ satisfy $d(p_{\varphi_1(n)}, q_1) < \dfrac{1}{2^{1+1}}$ (such $N_1$ exists by the definition of convergence). Suppose that $N_1 < \ldots < N_{i-1}$ have been defined. Define $N_i$ to be the first natural number $n > N_{i - 1}$ such that all $n \geq N_i$ satisfy $d(p_{\varphi_i(n)}, q_i) < \dfrac{1}{2^{i+1}}.$ Let $\psi_i = \varphi_i \circ \ldots \circ \varphi_1$ and $M_i = \varphi_{i-1} \circ \ldots \varphi_1(N_i),$ with $M_1 = N_1.$ Then $M_i \geq N_i$ and $\psi_i(N_i) = \varphi_i(M_i).$ Therefore, for all $i,$ $$d(p_{\psi_i(N_i)}, q) \leq d(p_{\varphi_i(M_i)}, q_i) + d(q_i, q) \leq \dfrac{1}{2^i}.$$
Thus, the subsequence $\left( p_{\psi_i(N_i)} \right)_i$ of $(p_n)$ converges to $q.$ *A fortiori*, $q \in E'.$ Q.E.D.

Answer (score 0):

> **for each $i∈N$, there is an $x∈E^∗$ such that $d(x,q)<2^{−i}$. Since $x∈E^∗$, there is an $n_i>n_i−1$ such that $d(x,p_{n_i})<2^{-i}$. So that
> $d(p_{n_i},q)<2^{-i}$
> So that ${p_{n_i}}→q?$**

What if your chosen $x$ turns out to be $q$? Then your argument becomes circular.

Comment: If $q = x,$ then you win because $x \in E^*.$